# Grails filter disables style/css

Tags: css, grails, grails-plugin

I made a security filter, following the book "Beginning Grails, Groovy and Griffon".

Looks like the functionality works ok, but, for some reason, the only page that the filter allows to open without a logged in user, is lacking any style. Just textfields, labels and buttons. Also the simple capthca plugin works and the captcha image is loaded ok.

Here's the page screenshot:

[image]

```
package collab.todo

class SecurityFilters {

def filters = {
    securityFilters(controller:'*', action:'*') {
        before = {
            if(!session.user && 
                (!controllerName.equals("user") && !actionName.equals("login") 
                    && !actionName.equals("captcha")
                     &&!actionName.equals("register")) ){
                redirect(controller: "user", action: "login")
            }
        }
        after = { Map model ->

        }
        afterView = { Exception e ->

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your page isn't displaying any assets (styles or images) is because in recent versions of Grails (2.3+) assets are served up by the asset pipeline plugin from the `/assets/**` URL.

Previous versions of Grails (for which your book was likely written) didn't use this plugin and as a result those assets weren't filterable.

To fix this issue you can use the exclusion properties of the filter (e.g. `uriExclude`). You can read more about it in the excellent [Grails documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters).

Here is an example of your filter with `uriExclude`:

```
package collab.todo

class SecurityFilters {

def filters = {
    securityFilters(controller:'*', action:'*', uriExclude: '/assets/**') {
        before = {
            if(!session.user && 
                (!controllerName.equals("user") && !actionName.equals("login") 
                    && !actionName.equals("captcha")
                     &&!actionName.equals("register")) ){
                redirect(controller: "user", action: "login")
            }
        }
        after = { Map model ->

        }
        afterView = { Exception e ->

        }
    }
}
}
```

This change will exclude applying your filter to anything under the `/assets/` URI, and your styles/images should now appear.

Comment: Yes, this fixed the problem. But why there are two asterisks in the assets path?

Comment: That's ant expression for "anything" (including sub directories).